# How do you save each file created by Indesign Data Merge

Tags: adobe-indesign, data-merge

I have used data merge to create 100 PDFs, how do I save each one individually with its own name?

Comment: You say to create 100 PDFs but are asking how to save them individually. So you mean you have 100 pages in a single PDF and now need to separate them?

Comment: The latter. I have a document with 100 combined PDFs, how do I create 100 single PDFs and save them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's scripts and plugins you can get to do this within InDesign but it doesn't do it (to my knowledge) natively.

I don't bother with scripts or plugins and instead will just open the PDF in Adobe Acrobat after and then its hard to find but go to:

Organize Pages → Split

That will let you separate the document into individual PDFs. You can also Extract and Combine PDF's using Acrobat.

[image]